# Multiple PayPal applications and verifying payments

Tags: android, ios, mobile, paypal

We are building multiple mobile apps (Iphone and Android). These are using the PayPal mobile SDK and we're verifying the payments on a backend. For each app we created a new application in PayPal, so that every app has it's own credentials.

Now I'm wondering if the backend needs to use different credentials for each application when verifying payments. Or can the backend use one of these credentials to verify all payments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use each App's credentials accordingly.  App A needs to use its credentials verify payments that it generates and App B needs to use its credentials to verify the payments that it processes.